# How can I pass a client-side parameter to a server-side route without using forms?

Tags: python, flask

I have a simple `Flask` web app. My *index* template has various ways of interacting with clients using javascript and `HTML`. I am also have a *form* that, upon submission, routes to another flask process and uses the `request.form` command to retrieve user-submitted data.

However, I want to do something a little different. I would like to initiate a `Flask` redirection upon `javascript` event but include a parameter, and not use *form*.

For example, my `index.html` file would display something like this after template rendering:

```
function startRedirect(parameter) {
    window.location.pathname = '/myRedirect';
}

<input type="checkbox" id="sample" name="sample" onChange="startRedirect(parameter);">
```

And part of my Flask script would have:

```
@app.route('/myRedirect')
def myRedirectFunction():
    # do something with the parameter here
    return render_template('index.html')
```

I realize this can be done with using a *form*, but I am interested in accomplishing this task without having a *form*. I was thinking about somehow using `request.args`, but don't quite understand what to do.

Comment: I'm _less sure_ about a checkbox here (why not a button?). `<a href="{{ url_for('the_flask_route_function_name') }}" class="button">Click to go to X</a>`

Comment: @roganjosh What you propose works well for initiating a redirect, but is there a way to pass a parameter to that redirect?

Comment: Have you considered using a dynamic route so you can pass a parameter to your route's function?  `app.route('/myRedirect/<param>')`

Comment: @James This is something I am very interested in, could you provide a simple use-case example?

Comment: Sure, what parameter do you want to pass? `<a href="{{ url_for('the_flask_route_function_name', param=param) }}" class="button">Click to go to X</a>` where the right side `param` is something that Jinja2 can access when rendering the template, and you have a view function like `@app.route('some_route/<param>')` which is looking for the name defined by the left side of `param=param`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dynamic route to capture a simple input and pass it to the route's function.

```py
app.route('/myRedirect/<param>')
def myRedirectFunction(param='hello world'):
    return render_template('index.html', param=param)
```

Using this route as a redirect, you can pass a single `param` (or multiple if you serialize them) that you can use to do *something*.  From there, you can either display or you can redirect again to a common endpoint so the user does not see the param in the url.

Comment: Why redirect? Just go straight to the route

Comment: Agree.  But that is not what he was asking.

Comment: Sure, but [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58808956/how-can-i-pass-a-client-side-parameter-to-a-server-side-route-without-using-form/58809066?noredirect=1#comment103897467_58808956) makes me think they might have gone off-course. We'll see.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for a form or an explicit `redirect`, just attach a route and some parameter to the dynamic route.

Let's say you have a model to list the departments in your company:

```
class Departments(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
```

Now you have a department selection page:

```
@app.route('/departments_home', methods=['GET'])
def departments_home():
    departments = Departments.query.all()
    return render_template('departments_home.html',
                           departments=departments)
```

On the frontend you might have a variety of selections, each giving a link to the same route but with a different department_id:

```
{% for department in departments %}
<a href="{{ url_for('load_department', department_id=department.id) }}" class="button">Click to go to {{ department.name }}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

Now you just need another route to handle this, taking the variable department_id that was passed in the GET request:

```
@app.route('/load_department/<department_id>', methods=['GET'])
def load_department(department_id):
   department = Departments.query.get(int(department_id))
   department_data = # do stuff here with the specific department
```